# Screen turns after off after a couple of minutes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, shutdown, screen, screensaver

When I turn on the computer my screen starts to turn on and off after a few minutes for a couple of times to then finally turn off. I then have to force a shutdown to then turn it on in the hope that the screen will stay on this time (usually it will stay on for about 10-20 minutes after the first forced shutdown).

I know it's not my HDMI-cable because before I had the window boot loader alongside the Ubuntu boot loader and there wasn't such an issue when I was on Windows.

I have been researching that issue online  to see if others had the same problem. I found some with the same problems and tried all kinds of solutions (like installing xscreensaver and turning off the screensaver).

If there's a solution, please explain it in simple terms, because I'm not that knowledgeable with the intricacies of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Well I assume you are using some brand of laptop having backlight issue in ubuntu, probably emachines(old acer) laptops shows off. I recommend you to create file and add contents as follows.

1. Become Root .

> ```
> sudo -i
> ```

2. Create a new file

> ```
> gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_backlight
> ```

3. Enter the following contents in it.

> #!/bin/sh
>
> #run 'setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00' when waking up
>
> ```
> case "$1" in
>         thaw|resume)
>            setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
>             ;;
> esac
> ```

4. Save the file.
5. Make it executable

> ```
> sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_backlight
> ```

6. Reboot your system.

> ```
> sudo reboot
> ```

Comment: @Sagar_Bhooshan It's not a laptop, it's a computer. But I will try that tomorrow anyways.